# Subscripcion del store de redux queda activa por más que no exista componente

Tags: angular, redux

En un Reducer de mi Store de Redux (NgRx) tengo una variable booleana que en caso de ser True, se mostrará un componente y en caso de ser False, no se mostrará.
Esto pasa en varias partes de mi proyecto pero voy a hablar de una en particular.

En mi componente se ve algo así:
component.ts

```
export class Component{
  isShowAddBuyer:boolean=false;

  constructor(private store:Store<AppState>){
    this.store.select('options').subscribe(options=>{      
      this.isShowAddBuyer=options.isShowAddBuyer;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Component.html:

```
...
<app-add-buyer class="slide-card slide-card-visible" *ngIf="isShowAddBuyer"></app-add-buyer>
...
```

Cuando se cambia el estado de la variable, el componente se muestra u oculta.

El inconveniente surge cuando en el componente AddBuyer, utilizamos también el Store de Redux.

```
export class AddBuyerComponent {
  ...
  constructor(...){
    this.store.select('options').subscribe(optionsR=>{
      this.isShowAddBuyer=optionsR.isShowAddBuyer;
      if(this.isShowAddBuyer){
        console.log("Show add")
        //ACCIONES
      } else if(!this.isShowAddBuyer){
        console.log("Not show add")
        //ACCIONES QUE SE EJECUTAN CUANDO NO SE VISUALIZA (ESTO NO DEBERÍA OCURRIR).
        //Porque el componente original no existe.
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Cuando inicio en el componente padre.
No aparece nada en la consola.

Una vez que se abre por primera vez el componente hijo, se visualiza "Show add".

Cuando se cierra, en la consola aparece "Not Show Add".

Queda la suscripción ejecutandosé.
Al ser una no habría problema pero esto ocurre con varios componentes y a medida que pasa el tiempo, entiendo que se va consumiendo la memoria.

Objetivo:

Lo que quiero hacer es que una vez que se destruya el componente, desuscribirme para que no me llegue mas información.
El problema es que lo intenté de varias formas y no lo logro conseguir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptuando los observables creados por HttpClient, que son capaces de anular las subscripciones cuando la petición concluye, hemos de cancelar las subscripciones que creamos cuando ya no son necesarias.

En cualquier componente puedes añadir el método `ngOnDestroy`, que se ejecutará cuando el componente deje de mostrarse:

```js
export class AddBuyerComponent {

  storeSubscription: Subscription;
  ...
  constructor(...){} //Angular recomienda NO añadir lógica en el constructor

  ngOnInit() { //se inicializa el componente
    this.storeSubscription = this.store.select('options').subscribe(optionsR=>{
      this.isShowAddBuyer=optionsR.isShowAddBuyer;
      if(this.isShowAddBuyer){
        console.log("Show add")
        //ACCIONES
      } else if(!this.isShowAddBuyer){
        console.log("Not show add")
        //ACCIONES QUE SE EJECUTAN CUANDO NO SE VISUALIZA (ESTO NO DEBERÍA OCURRIR).
        //Porque el componente original no existe.
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.storeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Una pregunta, en ningún momento haces referencia el Store al storeSubscription.
Puede ser que se tenga que inicializar cuando nos subscribimos? Es decir:

ngOnInit(){
   this.storeSubscription= this.store.subscribe(...)
}
 y despues desuscribir en OnDestroy

Comment: Vaya lapsus! Sí exactamente

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió eso exactamente.